# Android buttons not showing in phone

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have tried hard, figuring out what might be the problem.
I am trying to create a music player and the following is my XML file

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_btn_playlist_pressed"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:background="@null"/>

<TextView
    android:text="Select a song to play"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="1" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="51dp"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/forward"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/text" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_btn_previous_pressed"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:id="@+id/backward"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/forward"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/seekBar" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_btn_play"
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_row="21"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/backward"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_btn_forward_pressed"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/forward"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/play"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/text"
    android:layout_marginEnd="26dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_btn_repeat"
    android:id="@+id/repeat"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/forward"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/text"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />
```

And this is the screenshot of the above layout in Android studio.

[image: Screenshot]

The problem is, when I try to run the same on my phone, none of the buttons are showing up on the phone, only the `TextView` and the SeekBar is visible, rest none. What could be the problem? Why the buttons are not visible even though it seems fine in Android Studio...

PS: I am using RelativeLayout here.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: remove         android:background="@null" from all <ImageButton>

Comment: what is your phone and what is your android version 
and what is the language of your phone
this could happen because the rtl support in android 
try to cancel this support by adding 
 android:supportsRtl="false" to your application in manifests.xml

Comment: @MohamedFadhl I tried that, it didnt work...

Comment: @YogeshBorhade I don't think that ll work, that is just used for some other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Below Code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_btn_playlist_pressed"
        android:id="@+id/list"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Select a song to play"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="51dp"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/forward"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/text" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_btn_previous_pressed"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/backward"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/forward"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/seekBar" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_btn_play"
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_row="21"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/backward"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_btn_forward_pressed"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:id="@+id/forward"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/play"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/text"
        android:layout_marginEnd="26dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_btn_repeat"
        android:id="@+id/repeat"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/forward"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/text"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**if Still it will not work then use below code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img_btn_playlist_pressed"
        android:id="@+id/list"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Select a song to play"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="51dp"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/forward"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/text" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img_btn_previous_pressed"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/backward"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/forward"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/seekBar" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img_btn_play"
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_row="21"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/backward"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img_btn_forward_pressed"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:id="@+id/forward"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/play"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/text"
        android:layout_marginEnd="26dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img_btn_repeat"
        android:id="@+id/repeat"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/forward"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/text"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```